# TableView on simulator is not referencing correctly

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2

Hello and how is everyone?

When I run the simulation of my application I go to select the first object in the table. Nothing happens. I then go and select the second object and it performs the action that the first object was supposed to. Basically the first object is not active until I select it and then select another object.

Maybe this will help:
I turn the simulator on. I select the first object nothing happens(I have a print("what row I selected") within the didSelect function to make sure it is working.). But again no printout until I hit the second object, the second object should print #1 row selected but it says #0 row selected and then performs the segue setup for 0#. After I come back from the segue the first object still performs the same.

Here is my tableView Code:

```
var objects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.objects.addObject("help")
    self.objects.addObject("me")
    self.objects.addObject("please")
    self.objects.addObject("thankyou")

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(self.objects.count)
    return self.objects.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = self.objects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String


    return cell


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

     print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Typo.  We've all done this one! Autocomplete suggested `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` when you really wanted `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I'm fine, thanks. - you're implementing didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: when you meant to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I did it yesterday and thought I was going mad

Comment: Thank You so much everybody. I thought I was going crazy, I had to step away for a while. Now that my eyes aren't cross eyed anymore I can see the hidden mistake. Thanks again I really appreciate it.